# How to create OPA rego policy for a whitelist?

Tags: policy, opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I am trying to implement a whitelist policy in OPA rego. The purpose of the policy is to block all attributes except for attributes that have been whitelisted. However, I cannot get it to work.

Here is my rego policy:

```
package play

whitelisted_attributes =
{
    "foo.bar",
    "hello.from.*.world"
}

default allow = false
default not_in_whitelist = true

not_in_whitelist {
    whitelisted := {attr | attr := input.attributes[_]; glob.match(whitelisted_attributes[_], ["."], attr)}
    count(whitelisted) == 0
}

allow {
    not not_in_whitelist
}
```

Here is my input:

```
{
    "attributes": [
        "foo.bar"
    ]
}
```

Here is the output according to the Rego Playground:

```
{
    "allow": false,
    "not_in_whitelist": true,
    "whitelisted_attributes": [
        "foo.bar",
        "hello.from.*.world"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, "allow" should be true since the input is found in the whitelist. Also, "not_in_whitelist" should be false since the input attribute is in the whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that since one of the elements *is*  in the whitelist, the `not_in_whitelist` rule is going to evaluate to *undefined* (since that's what a rule where all conditions aren't met evaluates to).

Since `not_in_whitelist` evaluates to undefined, the rule will be assigned the **default** value of `true`:

```
default not_in_whitelist = true
```

The allow rule will then invert that in the `not` check, making the rule fail (since `not true` == `false`):

```
allow {
    not not_in_whitelist
}
```

I'd suggest simply removing the default assignment for `not_in_whitelist`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Devoops for your tip. I went back to the Rego Playground and after much trial and error came up with a working policy. I'm posting it here for others with similar needs.

```
package play

default allow = false
default in_whitelist = false

whitelist =
{
    "foo.bar",
    "hello.from.*.world"
}

num_attributes := count(input.attributes)

in_whitelist {
    glob.match(whitelist[_], ["."], input.attributes[_])
}

not_in_whitelist = result {
    num_attributes == 1
    result := (in_whitelist == false)
}

not_in_whitelist = result {
    num_attributes > 1
    whitelisted := {attr | attr := input.attributes[_]; glob.match(whitelist[_], ["."], attr)}
    result := (count(whitelisted) < num_attributes)
}

allow {
    not not_in_whitelist
}

deny[msg] {
    not_in_whitelist
    msg = sprintf("You are only allowed to modify the following whitelisted attributes: %v", [whitelist])
}
```